# Асинхронный вызов функций при определенном условии в разных компонентах

Tags: javascript, функции, асинхронность, token

**Ситуация**: есть экспортируемая функция, которая вызывается в **разных компонентах** проекта, чтобы отправить запрос на сервер с помощью fetch. Она подставляет внутри себя токен и проверку на то, что токен не просрочен, а потом делает запрос к серверу и ожидает ответ.

При заходе на сайт друг за другом все нужные запросы, допустим, 5 штук, проходящие через эту функцию, а потом идет ожидание ответа с сервера и последующая его обработка. Тут всё хорошо. Но допустим, токен оказался просроченным, и это определилось сразу после первого вызова данной функции.

Я начал отправлять внутри функции запрос к серверу для обновления токена, а значит, мне нужно временно ограничить вызов этой же функции в других компонентах, и после ответа с сервера продолжить их выполнение.

Примерный вид реализации основной функции:

```
const fetchAuth = async (url, n) => { //функция для запросов к API
    console.log(`fetchAuth function, time = ${time}`, n)
    if (time < 400) {
        await updTime();
    }

    const fetcher = fetch(url).then(res => {
        console.log(res.status, n);
    })
    return fetcher(url);
}
```

Функция для обновления токена, после выполнения которой можно продолжить выполнение функций:

```
const updTime = () => { //Функция для обновления времени жизни токена
    console.log(`updTime function, time = ${time}`)
    fetch(apiUrl).then(res => {
        time = 500;
        console.log(`time changed to ${time}`);
    })
}
```

Вызываются таким образом, но в разных компонентах:

```
fetchAuth(apiUrl, 1).then(res => { //Допустим, вызов в первом компоненте
    console.log({res}, 1); 
});

fetchAuth(apiUrl, 2).then(res => { //Допустим, вызов во втором компоненте
    console.log({res}, 2);
});
```

Полный код: https://codepen.io/kibnerk/pen/wvMKBYz

И получается, что обновление времени-токена происходит при каждом вызове.

Каким образом можно реализовать некий таймаут для выполнения последующих функций, если при вызове первой обнаружилось, что необходимое условие не соблюдается, и нужно дождаться ответа внутренней функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно замкнуть флаг текущей проверки в функции высшего порядка. В ней будет хранится `Promise` с резолвом токена. Если `Promise'a` нет и токен валидный, по сразу дергаем `mainFetch`. Если `Promise'a` нет и токен не валидный, создаем `Promise` с ожиданием ответа апдейта токена и `mainFetch` будет резолвится в `then`. Если `Promise` создан, функция `mainFetch` будет выполнена в `then` этого самого токен резолвер `Promise`.

```
let time = 300;

const updateTime = () => {
    console.log(`updateTime function, time = ${time}`)
    return fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(res => {
            time = 500;
            console.log(`time changed to ${time}`);
         })
    });
}

const fetchAuth = (() => {
    let tokenUpdatePromise = null;

    return (url, n) => {
        console.log(`fetchAuth function, time = ${time}`, n)
        if (time < 400 && !tokenUpdatePromise) {
            tokenUpdatePromise = updateTime();
        }

        return (tokenUpdatePromise || Promise.resolve())
            .then(() => fetch(url))
            .then((res) => console.log(res.status, n))
            .finally(() => tokenUpdatePromise = null)
    }
})();
```